# Excel Pivot Table Display

Tags: excel, pivot-table

This shouldn't be difficult, but I don't think I'm asking the correct answer when I search online.

I need to find the file that has the MAX depth.  My pivot table shows the API as row label and the Depth as Values Max of Depth. For this data:

```
API             FileName                Depth
42173309170000  Sonic _ Density_2_2.tif 10020
42173309170000  Sonic _ Density_2_3.tif 2860
42173309170000  Sonic _ Density_2_4.tif 10026
42173310310000  Sonic _ Density_3_5.tif 10900
42173310310000  Sonic _ Density_3_6.tif 3388
42173310310000  Sonic _ Density_3_7.tif 10940
42173311070000  Sonic_2_10.tif          11192
42173311070000  Sonic_2_5.tif           6200
42173311070000  Sonic_2_6.tif           8700
42173311070000  Sonic_2_7.tif           11190
42173311070000  Sonic_2_8.tif           6200
42173311070000  Sonic_2_9.tif           8704
42173312270000  Sonic_2_5.tif           11180
42173312270000  Sonic_2_6.tif           11186
```

What I want to display in the table is the API and the [1]File name associated with the Max depth (and only that one file name).

I want my pivot table to show

```
42173309170000  Sonic _ Density_2_4.tif 10026 (max for the first API number)
42173311070000  Sonic_2_10.tif          11192.00066 (max for the second API number)
```

etc.

I've tried various versions of display and subtotal, but I can't get this to work. Any help appreciated. I know this is really basic, but the file is quite large and I could really use the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, that's a tricky one. You can do it if you add a slicer for the API field, and then from the FileName filter dropdown select VALUES > Top 10...

[image]

...and then change the number of items from 10 to 1

[image]

...and then select one item at a time in the Slicer:

[image]

[image]

But that won't be much fun if you have many APIs to find the max for. How many are we talking?

Comment: Thanks.  238 in this file. 9 other files. *sigh*

Comment: No dramas...this can be done using VBA, I'm sure. Or perhaps with PowerQuery. Is everything laid out the same in all the files?

Comment: Yes. The files are identical.